# Overriding __libc_start_main to never call main function

Tags: c++, operating-system, dynamic-linking

I am currently trying to build a runtime system which calls main from a custom function with added functionalities on a different thread(therefore making main run twice, once with added functionalities and then from compilers version of main).

Is there a way I could re-implement the __libc_start_main compiler function to never call main, but call a custom function after initializing everything (similar to what it normally does, but this time call another function instead of main)?

Comment: Link with -nostartfiles, specify your own entry point in the linker script, and implement it as you wish.

Comment: There is an implementation example https://github.com/idunham/musl/blob/7e10f209fbc26a5179a4c0817c986e7c7bd327c9/crt/crt1.c